# Cannot use modulus only in query window that connected to server

Tags: sql-server, modulus

Currently I have a problem with SQL Server.

I just do a query like this :

```
declare @var2 int
set @var2 = ((7500.50 * 100) % 100)

select @var2
```

If I execute in local machine (query window connected to local), it returns 50.

But if I run that query in query window that is connected to my office server, it results in:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Operand data type numeric is invalid for modulo operator.
>   Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Operand type clash: int is incompatible with void type

I've tried in both SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Anyone ever face same problem or know the solution ?

Thanx a lot all.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [compatibility level](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-2005-change-database-compatible-level-backward-compatibility/) of the server.  It is likely at 80, which is for SQL Server 2000 compatibility.  In SQL Server 2000, modulo only supported the INT data types.  In [SQL 2005 and up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx), other numeric data types are allowed and implicit conversions will happen, since in your formula you have both numeric and integer data types.

I found a [script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ai/archive/2012/06/12/sql-server-set-comparability-level-for-all-server-databases.aspx) to modify compatibility level on all databases of a server with filtering of databases you wouldn't want to change.

Comment: Thanks @Sumo for your quick reply.<br />For the compability reason, my partner had used different computer but did as i did and He didn't get any problem like mine. So the problem maybe come from my computer or my both SQL Server 2005 and 2008..<br><br/>By the way, sorry for my bad english ^^